# ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'fog-aws' (= 0.8.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, fog, fog-aws

I am using ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0 . i added 
gem 'fog'
gem "fog-aws"

on my gem file when i am trying to bundle install, getting following error

```
An error occurred while installing fog-aws (0.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install fog-aws -v '0.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.

ranjith@Ranjith-laptop:~/projects/recruitement$ gem install fog-aws -v '0.8.1' ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'fog-aws' (= 0.8.1), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - server did not return a valid file (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Comment: It works for me when I tried it, might just have been a temporary glitch in rubygems.org. I'd try again, if that still fails, maybe try and install another gem to see if you're getting wider issues. If you're using rvm, try install into another ruby version.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like that's a temporary rubygems issue.  fog-aws 0.8.1 is available https://rubygems.org/gems/fog-aws/versions/0.8.1.  I'd try 0.9.1 instead.